# How can we assign different signals to a single integer value?

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing  VHDL test bench for full adder

in Simulation i have tried this and getting the correct result

```
   begin        
            A <= '0';
            B <= '0';
            C <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns; 
            A <= '0';
            B <= '0';
            C <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns; 
            A <= '0';
            B <= '1';
            C <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
            A <= '0';
            B <= '1';
            C <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns;
            A <= '1';
            B <= '0';
            C <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
            A <= '1';
            B <= '0';
            C <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns;
            A <= '1';
            B <= '1';
            C <= '0';
            wait for 10 ns;
            A <= '1';
            B <= '1';
            C <= '1';
            wait for 10 ns;
      wait;
   end process;
```

but i don't want to write all this i just want to use for loop like in verilog

```
for i in 0 to 7 loop
    {A,B,C} <= i;  
    wait for 10 ns;
end loop;
```

I Know assigning A, B, C to i is not right in VHDL?
how do we do that what are the correct syntax?

Comment: The title of this question doesn't properly reflect the problem. You're assigning different signals not an integer value.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can - VHDL 2008 allows aggregate assignments.

```
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

for i in 0 to 7 loop
  (A,B,C) <= to_slv(i, 3);
  wait for 10 ns; 
end loop;
```

Comment: -1987 through -2002 also allow assignments to aggregates. IEEE Std 1076-2008  9,3.3.2 Array aggregates adds (paragraph 3)  "For an element association with a choice that is a discrete range and an expression of the type of the aggregate, each element of the value of the expression is the value of the element of the aggregate at the matching index value in the range. ..."  which is not required here. a, b, and c are of the element type, the aggregate is compatible with earlier revisions.

Comment: Also see 'VHDL-2008 Just the New Stuff', Ashensen, Lewis, 6.4 Slices in Aggregates paragraph 2 which introduces the -2008 change without requiring comparison of the different revisions text or analysis of Language Change Specifications.

Answer (score 4):

This work under **VHDL93** with Vivado 2018.1:

```
loop1: for i in 0 to 7 loop
    (a,b,c) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,3));
    wait for 10ns;
end loop;
```

You will not need the library `use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;` (which I do not know)
But you will need the standard ieee library:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
```

Here is the testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL; 
library work;

entity test_tb is

end entity;

architecture Behavioral of test_tb is

    signal clk : std_logic;
    signal a : std_logic;
    signal b : std_logic;
    signal c : std_logic;
begin

    clkpr : process
    begin
        clk <='1';
        wait for 10ns;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 10ns;
    end process;

    test_pr : process
    begin

        loop: for i in 0 to 7 loop
            (a,b,c) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,3));
            wait for 10ns;
        end loop;

        wait;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: numeric_std_unsigned is a 2008 library.
Also, `(A,B,C) <= sig` is a 2008 Construct

Comment: yes, I have discovered that thanks to you, also, I have post this answer so that people that want to use VHDL93 can. I have never used `numeric_std_unsigned` and I have rarely seen this library being used (but I have little experience). I have created a post about libraries: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458373/should-we-use-ieee-numeric-std-unsigned maybe you can share with us why we should use numeric_std_unsigned ?

Comment: `(A,B,C) <= sig is a 2008 Construct` It works with vivado 2018.1 using VHDL93.

Comment: The preceding 2 comments are inaccurate. This answer is valid for revisions -1987 thru -2008 using an aggregate assignment target. See IEEE Std 1076-1987 7.3.2 Aggregates, 8.3 Signal Assignment Statements. What -2008 adds to aggregates is choices (in a positional or named association) that are of the aggregate type (here std_logic_vector from context, a choice representing a range of elements) in addition to the previously supported choices of the element type (here a,b, c are compatible with the element type of std_logic_vector).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;    -- To use integer and unsigned

...

signal stimuli : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- Equivalent of A, B, C

...

inst_full_adder : full_adder
port map
(
  i_a     => stimuli(0),
  i_b     => stimuli(1),
  i_carry => stimuli(2),
  ...
);

...

for i in 0 to 7 loop
  stimuli <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,3));  -- Conversion of your integer in std_logic_vector (3 is the size of your vector)
  wait for 10 ns;
end loop;
```